# A slang word for person who is addicted to mass media promoted pop-culture

Tags: single-word-requests, slang, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

I am looking for a slang term which describes people who are all about contemporary mass media promoted pop culture: pop song charts, YouTube likes, dislikes and comments, celebrities' instagrams, etc. A slang word for a person who is extremely dependent on "currently in the top" people's lives.

The person who follows celebrities on social media day by day and comments on every photo and YouTube video with something like "justin rocks☺☺", "Who''ll watch This In JANUARY 2016?", "Who's Watching This In FEBRUARY 2016?". The context should be somewhat cynical. Something like "pop-headed", "likes-headed", "YouTube-thumbs-upper", etc.

Do you have any suggestions?

**Update 1**: The words "twit" and particularly "ditz" are close to what I am looking for.

Comment: Someone who down-voted - please explain me how should I improve the question!

Comment: Use less weighted/biased language,eg remove ' mind is garbaged ".

Also, it appears that you've got two things going that you're trying to address - one is the use of social media, the other is an obsession with pop culture, which apparently you have disdain for.

Comment: @dwjohnston, thank you. I have corrected my question accordingly.

Comment: Maybe a *twit*?

Comment: Maybe a *facebookworm*?

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for something mean or neutral? Not sure I can help with a neutral descriptor, but any number of nasty ones come to mind.

Consumer whore, ditz, twit, shallow superficial...

Kardashian? That could probably be made into a general-purpose adjective.

Comment: Thank you! The word "ditz" is very close to what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Old standbys like *boring,* *superficial,* and *bubbleheaded* come to mind.

Comment: Good, but too generic. Are there other words which are more specific to mass media induced pop euphory?

Answer (score 1):

There is the slang term ***social media whore*** derived from *attention whore*. It is defined in *[urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Social%20Media%20Whore)* as:

> A person who has a psychological need to receive @replies and pings on twitter, attention at tweetups, facebook status update comments, and facebook likes.
>
> This person usually becomes aroused almost sexually by seeing or hearing themselves or about themselves on social media websites.

You can find the term on other websites and social media sites as well. For example, [*totalsororitymove.com*](http://totalsororitymove.com/5-types-of-attention-whores/) mentions it as one of the five types of attention whores. The website *[dose.com](http://www.dose.com/food/2150/15-Amazing-Cakes-For-The-Social-Media-Whore-In-Your-Life)* lists fifteen cakes for the social media whore in your life.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider the word ***otaku.*** The term was coined in 1983. Today it is often misunderstood by Americans to refer to someone who is obsessed with anime, but the meaning is just what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say ditz, twit, or pop culture princess.

Comment: Hello, BiblioChic. Answers giving reasonable references are best on ELU. Also, duplicate answers (twit; ditz) should be avoided.